# Java Call class function from loaded class

Tags: java, classloader

How would I, if possible, call a function in my Main class in the class that I load? (I know that is impossible to understand, so I'll explain)

I.E:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public SomeClass
     {
          //load a class here
     }

     public void FuncToCall() {}
}

//In a separate file, dynamically loaded.
public class LoadedClass
{
     public LoadedClass
     {
          //Call a function in the class that loads this
          SomeClass.FuncToCall();
     }
}
```

So I would end up having 2 files: SomeClass.class and LoadedClass.class. I guess my main question is, how do I reference SomeClass in LoadedClass?

**EDIT:

So maybe I should better explain the use case. A java program dynamically loads the "SomeClass" script from a folder. The script then downloads a .jar file from the internet and opens and runs the "LoadedClass" script within that. How do I use functions in SomeClass in LoadedClass if SomeClass isn't in the same .jar or in a .jar at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I don't think I fully understand your question.  Can you elaborate on just what it is that you're trying to do and why your current approach isn't working?

Comment: Well, I haven't actually tried to compile it yet. I guess I should try. Maybe I have Compilation Errorphobia. XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do it..

If they are in different packages you have to either import the class or use the fully qualified name.

Let me see if I get it.

Check this running sample with modifications to your source code:

```
C:\Users\oreyes\java>type SomeClass.java LoadedClass.java Main.java
//SomeClass.java
public class SomeClass{
     public SomeClass () /* added () */ {
          //load a class here
          LoadedClass lc = new LoadedClass( this );
     }
     public  void funcToCall() {
         System.out.println("SomeClass.functToCall: Being invoked :)");
     }
}
//LoadedClass.java
//In a separate file, dynamically loaded.
public class LoadedClass {
     public LoadedClass( SomeClass sc )/*added () */ {
          //Call a function in the class that loads this
          //SomeClass.funcToCall();
          sc.funcToCall();
     }
}
//Main.java
//
public class Main {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        new SomeClass();
    }
}
C:\Users\oreyes\java>javac SomeClass.java LoadedClass.java Main.java
C:\Users\oreyes\java>java Main
SomeClass.functToCall: Being invoked :)
C:\Users\oreyes\java>
```

What a did was to pass a reference of the loader class into the loaded, and from there...just invoke the method.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

As per your comment it looks like what you need is to use [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: Well, neither are in ANY packages. I'm writing scripts for a program that just requires you to implement their interface. and I'm wanting to program a loader that loads different scripts. So neither the Loader or the Scripts are in any packages. So how would I reference them? Or do I have to reference them?

Comment: How can you pass arguments using Class.newInstance()?

Comment: Oh.. I see. you can't you have to load the class with `class.forName()` and from the returned Class objetct you have to get a constructor that receives the type http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...) and then create it with `Constructor.newInstance` method: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)  What you're looking for is called: "Reflection"

Comment: I was able to compile the code, and run it. Except when the onStart() function is called, I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

You do it right now.

We call it --> Recursivity (if you call the same function from the function you call)
Or simply.. a redirection.. You learn little by little what is the POTENTIAL of the programming :D

Welcome to StackOverflow :D
Good Luck!

Comment: I tried compiling. It didn't know what Class I was trying to call from.

Comment: because if you call a class from another class, you need to create an object before. (OOP) LOOK at the big answer
Example: 

`Class X{ public functionX(){}}
Class Y { 
        public functionY(){ 
                 X object = new X(); //Create an object to access to the function X
                 object.functionX(); //you call the function from Class X
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

because if you call a class from another class, you need to create an object before. (OOP) 
Example:

```
Class X{ public functionX(){}}
Class Y { 
   X object = new X(); //Create an object to access to the function X
    public functionY(){ 
             object.functionX(); //you call the function from Class X
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still lies in the fact that neither X nor Y is in a package and they are in seperate files. How do you reference to them in that situation?

Comment: Even if they are separate files.. if they are in the same `Project`, you can call it. But, create your object at the outside. I Update my answer